# Puppeteer element is console.log'able but return undefined in puppeteer

Tags: web-scraping, web-crawler, puppeteer, domcrawler

I'm trying to crawl a webpage that has a `h3` tag under an `a` tag. I'm getting the `a` tag just fine, but when trying to get the innerText of `h3` I'm getting an `undefined` value.

This is what I'm trying to crawl:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const pageURL = "https://producthunt.com";

const webScraping = async pageURL => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        arges: ["--no-sandbox"]
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    let dataObj = {};

    try {
        await page.goto(pageURL, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });

        const publishedNews = await page.evaluate(() => {
            const newsDOM = document.querySelectorAll("main ul li");

            let newsList = [];
            newsDOM.forEach(linkElement => {
                const text = linkElement.querySelector("a").textContent;
                const innerText = linkElement.querySelector("a").innerText;
                const url = linkElement.querySelector("a").getAttribute('href');

                const title = linkElement.querySelector("h3").innerText;
                console.log(title);

                newsList.push({
                    title,
                    text,
                    url
                });
            });
            return newsList;
        });

        dataObj = {
            amount: publishedNews.length,
            publishedNews
        };

    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }

    console.log(dataObj);
    browser.close();
    return dataObj;
};

webScraping(pageURL).catch(console.error);
```

Console log works great, but puppeteer throws:

```js
Cannot read property 'innerText' of null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your solution is working just fine, but you're not controlling whether the `h3` tag is null or not. Try adding an `if` statement before accessing the innerText attribute, or use the code I left below.

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const pageURL = "https://producthunt.com";

const webScraping = async pageURL => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        arges: ["--no-sandbox"]
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    let dataObj = {};

    try {
        await page.goto(pageURL, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });

        const publishedNews = await page.evaluate(() => {
            let newsList = [];
            const newsDOM = document.querySelectorAll("main ul li");

            newsDOM.forEach(linkElement => {
                const aTag = linkElement.querySelector("a");

                const text = aTag.textContent;
                const innerText = aTag.innerText;
                const url = aTag.getAttribute('href');

                let title = aTag.querySelector("h3");
                // there may be some <a> without an h3, control
                // the null pointer exception here, accessing only
                // if title is not 'null'.
                if (title) title = title.innerText;

                console.log(title);

                // changed the object structure to add a key for each attr
                newsList.push({
                    title: title,
                    text: text,
                    url: url
                });
            });

            return newsList;
        });

        // changed the object structure to add a key for the array
        dataObj = {
            amount: publishedNews.length,
            list: publishedNews
        };

    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }

    console.log({receivedData: dataObj});
    browser.close();
    return dataObj;
};

webScraping(pageURL).catch(console.error);
```

Let me know if this fixes your problem!